# What is the equivalent of Drupal.settings.basePath?

Tags: 8, javascript

I'm trying to get the site URL in JavaScript. In Drupal 7, this is stored in `Drupal.settings.basePath`. What's the Drupal 8 equivalent?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

In Drupal 8 this setting is:

```
drupalSettings.path.baseUrl
```

You find more in `core/module/system/system.module`:

```
function system_js_settings_alter(&$settings, AttachedAssetsInterface $assets) {
  ...
    $path_settings = [
    'baseUrl' => $request->getBaseUrl() . '/',
    'pathPrefix' => $pathPrefix,
    'currentPath' => $current_path,
    'currentPathIsAdmin' => $current_path_is_admin,
    'isFront' => \Drupal::service('path.matcher')->isFrontPage(),
    'currentLanguage' => \Drupal::languageManager()->getCurrentLanguage(LanguageInterface::TYPE_URL)->getId(),
  ];

  ...
```

Comment: Perfect, just have to make sure the dependency is declared `- core/drupalSettings` https://www.drupal.org/theme-guide/8/assets

Answer (score 3):

Use Drupal.url()

ref: docroot/core/misc/drupal.js

Comment: It makes sense to make use of the core function, thanks !